# I want to convert SQL to Linq query

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Here is my SQL query that I want to convert into Linq

```
SELECT 
    s.Studentname,
    COUNT(c.StudentId)
FROM  
    Students s, StudentCourses c
WHERE 
    s.StudentId = c.StudentId
GROUP BY
    s.Studentname
```

> And here am trying with linq to store Data in StudentDto Model

```
var students = (from s in DbContext.students
                    join sc in DbContext.studentCourses on 
                    s.StudentId equals sc.StudentId
                    group s by s.Studentname into grouped
                    select new StudentDto()
                    {
                        Studentname = s.StudentName,
                        StudentEmail = s.StudentEmail,
                        PhoneNumber = s.PhoneNumber,
                        DateOfBirth = s.DateOfBirth,
                        Password = s.Password,
                        ConfirmPawword = s.ConfirmPawword,
                        CourseCount = sc.count()
                    }
                    ).ToList();
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What are your tries? Please read SO guide before asking about your homeworking.

Comment: This would be a perfect example for your first usage of linq. https://linqsamples.com/

Comment: Always mention the EF version and show the class model. Without that kind of info we can  only guess which solution is possible.

Answer (score 1):

An idomatic LINQ query would simply be:

```
from s in db.Students
select new {s.StudentName, CourseCount = s.Courses.Count() };
```

Comment: i want to group by with studentName

Comment: Unless multiple students have the same StudentName, you don't need to.  The query in my answer returns one row per Student.

Comment: I have Edited my QUeastion Review it Please .ok i will group by StudentID and want to store data in studentDto model with count of Courses

Comment: Yep.  No need to join.  Just query the student and use the Courses Navigation Property to count.